# asymptotic behavior of generating function of partitions $p(n)$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, modular-forms

I want to show the following asymptotic behavior.

Let $P(q)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p(n)q^n$ be the generating function of the partitions $p(n)$ and $q=\exp(2\pi i \tau).$

I want to prove the following asymptotic behavior using the modularity of the dedekind $\eta$ function.

$\eta(\tau+1)=\eta(\tau)\exp(\frac{\pi i}{12}).$

$\eta(-\frac{1}{\tau})=\eta(\tau)\sqrt{-\tau i}.$

And we get $P(q)=\frac{q^{\frac{1}{24}}}{\eta(\tau)}.$

> Prove
>   $P(q)\sim \sqrt{-\tau i}\exp(\frac{\pi i}{12\tau})$ for $\tau \to 0$ where $\tau \in \mathbb H.$

[Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function)

Comment: So, what have you tried? How far did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with the definition
$\;P(\tau) := \exp(\pi i\tau/12)/\eta(\tau)\;$ where $\tau \in \mathbb H.$
Replacing $\tau$ with $-1/\tau$ gives
$\;P(-1/\tau) \exp(\frac{\pi i}{12\tau}) = 1/\eta(-1/\tau).\;$
Using modularity  gives
$\;1/(\eta(\tau)\sqrt{\tau/i}) =  1/\eta(-1/\tau).$
Combining the last two equations gives
$\;P(-1/\tau)\sqrt{\tau/i}\exp(\frac{\pi i}{12\tau}) = 1/\eta(\tau).\;$
Substituting this in the definition of $P(\tau)$ gives
$\;P(\tau) = \exp(\pi i\tau/12) P(-1/\tau)\sqrt{\tau/i}\exp(\frac{\pi i}{12\tau}).$
Since the first two factors approach $1$ as $\tau\to0$ we have our asymptotic result $\;P(q)\sim \sqrt{\tau/i}\exp(\frac{\pi i}{12\tau}).$